# Best way to store code_challenge and code_challenge_method in OAuth2(PKCE flow)

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, pkce

##### OAuth2(PKCE flow)

A client app makes a call to **/authorize** endpoint of the authorization server with *code_challenge* and *code_challenge_method*. Both *code_challenge* and *code_challenge_method* are required in the subsequent requests of the authorization server along with user credentials to generate the authorization code.

I can think of 2 options for how to store *code_challenge* and *code_challenge_method* to use in the subsequent calls:

1. persist the *code_challenge* and *code_challenge_method* before redirecting to the login page or user consent page
2. pass the *code_challenge* and *code_challenge_method* to the login page in query parameters, those then will be submitted along with the credentials

As [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636) does not talk about this much, which option is better and why, or are there any other options? Please suggest.

Also, are there any best design practices about authorization server endpoints(except **/authorize** and **/token**) implementations in OAuth2(PKCE flow)?

Comment: code_verifier comes into the picture after the code is generated, my question is about user authentication in OAuth2(PKCE) flow.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 7636 Section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636#section-4.4) states (emphasis mine):

> Typically, the "code_challenge" and "code_challenge_method" values
> are stored in encrypted form in the "code" itself but could
> alternatively be stored on the server associated with the code.  The
> server MUST NOT include the "code_challenge" value in client requests
> **in a form that other entities can extract**.

This rules out your option 2, as the challenge would be available in plain text to the user agent. It *does* however specify another option to encode this information into the `code` value, but it seems like this is not what you're looking for.

You're looking for a way to store the challenge while redirecting the user to the login page, *before* generating the `code`. In this case you could store the challenge in an encrypted `httpOnly` cookie in order to maintain a stateless design. A successful login would redirect the user agent back to your `/authorize` endpoint where you can extract the cookie again and generate the authorization response.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Add Login Using the Authorization Code Flow with PKCE](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/add-login-using-the-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce)

There are 2 codes when doing PKCE :

1. Code verifier, the random string
2. Code challenger, the hashed string from the code verifier, and his hash method, the code_challenge_method

In the Oauth2 authorization_code flow, a client needs 2 tokens:

1. authorization token, to request accessToken
2. accessToken, to access resources

To get the authorization token with PKCE, a client app will have to pass the code challenger & method in the URL parameter, then the user is redirected to login page.

After login, the authorization server redirect user back to the client app, with authorization token in url parameters.

Finally the client app request access token with authorization token, code verifier, client id, and all other parameters.

When the ressources server receive the request for access token, it has to "remember" which code challenge to use to test with the code verifier.

Suppose there are 1000 users authorizing in the same time, there will be 1000 authorizations & code challengers per app client id.

The authorization server should accurately find the right user (authorization & code challenge) along the 1000 users to verify the code & generate access code.

I think this answers your question, storing code challenge after user login, which means pass it to login page (but encrypted, because there is a code challenge methode named plain...)

I don't see how we can link the user & code challenge when the authorization server first receive the authorization request.

Comment: Hi, my question is about saving code_challenge, and code_challenge_method on the authorization server while the user authenticates herself/himself.