# How to juggle multiple PKCE code_verifiers in a monolithic OAuth2 "client" that is really a Web server

Tags: oauth-2.0, aes, okta, pkce

I'm implementing Oauth2 with PKCE in a monolithic application written in Spring 5.2 (not Boot) with Struts 2.5. The application currently keeps users and hashed passwords in its own database, but I'm changing it to use the corporate OAuth2 Okta authorization server, which requires PKCE. From my research, most PKCE implementations have the client side of the OAuth 2.0 protocol flow happen inside a browser that's dealing only with one user at a time.

By contrast, in my case the OAuth2 "client" is really a web server. I have a Struts action on the server that assembles the URI to the authorization server's endpoint, including the transformed code_verifier (code_challenge), and redirects the user's browser to that endpoint. A second Structs action handles the PKCE callback from that authorization server and calls the token endpoint on the authorization server behind the browser's back to obtain an access token for the user's session.

Between the start and the end of the PKCE interaction this "client" web server has to keep track of code verifiers for potentially many users all trying to login at the same time. I can think of two possibilities:

- Maintain a map keyed by the random *state* parameter that is posted to the authorization server in the initial challenge and returned to the callback action. There would have to be a mechanism to purge stale entries from this map that remain from incomplete login interactions.
- Generate a random AES key at web server startup which is used solely for encrypting the code verifier, sending the encrypted code verifier as the *state* parameter, and then decrypting the state in the callback action to recover the code verifier. This wouldn't require maintaining a map in the web server, just this random key. Is there anything insecure with this approach?

I've implemented the second possibility above, and it works, but hasn't been rolled out to production yet for hackers to play with.

If the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75514451/1599338) (also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77026877/1599338)) is secure (store the code verifier in an encrypted cookie), then I think my solution would also be secure, but is it necessary to opt for the complexity of a cookie instead of simply the *state* parameter?

Comment: **Having a web server be an OAuth2 (confidential) client is now the rule** (public clients as required by SPAs are now discouraged) and you should not have anything special to do. Spring Security 5 for OAuth2 clients supports `authorization_code` with PKCE (using Boot just eases the configuration, not the core features). In Spring OAuth2 clients, the tokens are stored by default in session (see `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` hierarchy), and so is the code verifier. All user-agents have (unauthorized) sessions as soon the first request is sent (just state of session changes after login).

Comment: I decided to store the code verifier and state as HttpSession attributes so as not to possibly risk exposing the code verifier to the user's browser. I coded all this myself instead of relying on Spring as the version of Spring Security we're running (5.7.7) doesn't appear to support PKCE even though it's v5.